# Best Practice - Update LastModifiedDate (Cross Object)

Tags: apex, trigger, opportunity, activities, cross-object

I have a business requirement to change `LastModifiedDate` on an `Opportunity` record whenever an `Activity` is logged against it.

I can do it in two ways:

1. when an activity is logged, i can simply do an update statement on the Opportunity record.
2. Or I can update the Activity createdDate into LastModifiedDate of the Opportunity.

Which approach should I take? Updating the whole record or updating one field (I am in a dilemma because both are going to cause all workflows and triggers to fire).

Comment: You can't directly manipulate the LastModDate.

Comment: But based on online dev forum posts if i activate Audit Trails in my Org i can directly write into System fields, will it not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just update the records. Even if you could write to the `LastModifiedDate`, it would then just change to the time at which you are performing the update, I think. There is no reason to go to extra effort to update the `LastModifiedDate` specifically. As you mention yourself, this will still cause triggers and workflows to fire.